# Prevent ElasticSearch to Crash at Large Number of Concurrent Request

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am using ElasticSearch6.2.1. I am using single node cluster. It is working fine with my small size indices and medium traffic. But when I test for large number of concurrent request to handle using Apache JMeter, ES is going down with error message like below.

[image]

My requirement is to prevent ES to not crash even in such high traffic situation. It should discard requests after a certain time but not to stop working. Is there any option by which I can achieve it? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

if the requests are going up for just few seconds, you can increase the queue size of requested thread_pool (for example search thread-pool). otherwise you should add some node to cluster.
(please add some log of elastic crashing. do you have any out of memory exception?)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure elasticsearch is crashing? here, it's saying the search thread pool is full.

More read at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html.